# What is the difference in Future consructors?

Tags: dart, future

What is the difference in these Future consructors?

It seems they do and act the same way and the results are identical, arn't they?

```
Future<double> future1 = Future(() => 36.6);

Future<double> future2 = Future.value(36.6);
```

Comment: Yes, they will yeld the same results

Answer (score 1):

`Future(callback)` gives the DOM time to react and doesn't go into the `runAsync` queue.

`Future.value(value)` behaves like a Future that was completed earlier (it's completely valid to keep these Future.values around instead of creating a new one every time) and it does go into the `runAsync` queue.

Have a look on the example below (it returns 1,2,**4,3** instead of 1,2,**3,4**):

```dart
    void main() {
      Future.value().then((_) {
        print(1);
        Future(() => print(3));
      });

      Future.value().then((_) {
        print(2);
        Future.value().then((_) => print(4));
      });
    }
```